# Why can't I use generics with CreateCriteria in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, generics

In my Base repo I have this code which works fine:

```
abstract class BaseRepo <T> : IRepo <T>
{
    private ISession _session;

    public Entity GetById<Entity>(int Id)
    {
        return _session.Get<Entity>(Id);
    }

    // other methods
}
```

I want to add another method to return all rows for an object (entity). I want to do something like:

```
    public IList<Entity> GetAll<Entity>()
    {
        return _session.CreateCriteria<Entity>().List<Entity>;
    }
```

but I get an error saying:

```
The type 'Entity' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'NHibernate.ISession.CreateCriteria<T>()'
```

Here's my DAL design for reference: [Should I use generics to simplify my DAL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823194/should-i-use-generics-to-simplify-my-dal)

Comment: What does the definition for `Entity` look like?

Comment: `Entity` is generic and can be any object in my domain. I have `Account`, `Broker`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CreateCriteria` method requires you to use reference types - add constraint on your DAL method:

```
public IList<Entity> GetAll<Entity>()
     where Entity : class
{
    return _session.CreateCriteria<Entity>().List<Entity>();
}
```

This naturally implies that any `Entity` type you pass to this method must be a reference type.

I also suggest naming your generic type parameter `TEntity` - `Entity` alone is a bit confusing (as it's perfectly fine name for say, entity base class).

Comment: Thanks that builds OK, but when I exercise it in my unit test I get this error: `M:Test.RepoTest.CanGetAllAccounts failed: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Is your `_session` set to an actual instance? How `CanGetAllAcounts` test method looks like? Do you use any test setup method? There can be multiple reasons for NRE, without more code it's really hard to tell.

Comment: Oh no i feel so dumb. I had forgotten to put my [Test] attribute on my test. Once I had done that it worked. Doh!