# Get generic list by criteria

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

Let's say i have following tables in database:

[image]

I want to get a list of all the children with a specific dadId and also i want to re-use this method for other criterias.

Is it something like this that i would use ?

```
 public IList<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        return Session.CreateCriteria<T>()
           //add restriction
            .List<T>();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, a clean idea. But unfortunately no.

Answer (score 1):

No.

`list<T>` may return `list<Object[]>` depending on the Criteria you have.

You can write a wrapper but this is a lot of Overhead.

Comment: Okey, do you have a better solution then?

Comment: Im new to NHibernate and im not sure what you mean with wrapper. Can you be a little more specific please? Thank you.

Comment: A wrapper is a bigger kind of the Adapter-Patter from Gang-of-Four. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889160/what-is-a-wrapper-class

Comment: I am a little bit confused... you are using generics like a pro, but dont know about wrappers?! :D  .... maybe i am just old!

Comment: Haha,I know what a wrapper is, but im not sure how to use it in this case. Will it be like this: return Session.CreateCriteria<Wrapper>() and .List<Wrapper> because it complains on having T in CreateCriteria<T> ? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public IList<T> GetAll<T>()
     where T : class
{
    return _session.CreateCriteria<T>().List<T>();
}
```

Works fine for me! Vote!
Similar answer here - [Why can't I use generics with CreateCriteria in NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839803/why-cant-i-use-generics-with-createcriteria-in-nhibernate)

Any reason why i didnt get a vote on this?  this code works for me and it appears to be exactly that the user is looking for.  Did i miss something?